# Backpropagating with ReLu function

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I was learning about activation functions in neural networks. Problem with a simple linear function is referred below:

> A = cx, derivative with respect to x is c. That means the gradient has no relationship with X. It is a constant gradient and the descent is going to be on a constant gradient. If there is an error in prediction, the changes made by backpropagation is constant and not depending on the change in input delta(x) !!!

A derivative of the ReLu function is also a constant. My question is "How can we backpropagate with ReLu function when its derivative is a constant and not depending on the change in input?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a math question, not a programming one.

Answer (score 0):

Linear functions are not used as activation functions in neural networks.

ReLU activation function is defined as

f(x) = max(0,x)

It is not linear and its derivative is not constant. The derivative is 0 for negative x and 1 for positive x.